# Javascript / XML - Handling emojis

Tags: javascript, xml, xpath

I'm having a small issue with  handling Emojis sent by JavaScript to our backend, we use XML in our backend and JSON in our frontend.

When trying to apply xpath expression's on the XML cointaining '', but it's not represented as the actual emoji, it's represented as '¿#55357;¿#56864;'

I'm getting this error message 'Character reference "&#55357" is an invalid XML character.'

How would I handle emojis? Is there anything I could do in Javascript to prevent this from happening but still being able to send/read emojis..?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: XML is not going to understand the unicode for an emoji. You need to use a server side language to parse unicode structure into something the doc will understand. https://www.w3.org/TR/unicode-xml/ It would depend on your server side lang for the best approach. maybe there is a library or something that will do this for you.

Comment: Well we have a framework which is built upon Java running in the server side, but our business logic is configured in an XML file, which describes a 'pipeline' to run a HTTP call trough.. https://github.com/ibissource/iaf

Comment: Look here, this is what you need. https://github.com/vdurmont/emoji-java